# Is it possible to add an App from the SharePoint Online store to a site with PowerShell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

Is it possible to install an app, that is on the SharePoint Online app store, on a SharePoint site using PowerShell?

If so how is this done?

I had a look at the documentation and found that the only example that Microsoft give is done by importing the app, not deploying it from the store. This can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-server/install-spapp?view=sharepoint-ps).

Answer (score 0):

GSDs solution does not answer the question. I tried it and its not working. With the solution he proposed its only possible to add an app from the app catalogue. The initial question was how you can add an app directly from the SharePoint online store.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/117711)

Comment: I'm not asking for clarification from the asker. I'm stating that the answer provided is wrong. I also dont have the right answer to this question because I'm also searching for how to solve this. But what I definitly know that the proposed solution doesnt work. This could help anyone else searching for Help here. What am I supposed to do? Ask the same question again and say that this is not a solution?

Comment: You are supposed to downvote the answer and leave a comment on it (which you can do with enough reputation)

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using the below PnP PowerShell command which does not require to import the app, directly we can install to the site :

Example 1.

```
Install-PnPApp -Identity 99a00f6e-fb81-4dc7-8eac-e09c6f9132fe -Scope Site
```

This will install an app that is available in the site collection scoped app catalog, specified by the id, to the current site.

Example 2.

```
Get-PnPAvailableApp -Identity 99a00f6e-fb81-4dc7-8eac-e09c6f9132fe | Install-PnPApp
```

This will install the given app from the tenant scoped app catalog into the site.

More details about the above command :

[Install-PnPApp](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/install-pnpapp?view=sharepoint-ps)

To install or set up PnP PowerShell, refer the below :

[Office 365: Getting started with SharePoint PnP PowerShell – installation](https://global-sharepoint.com/powershell/office365-sharepoint-pnp-powershell-installation/)

This is another way of adding app using PnP PowerShell:

```
function AddApp($SiteFullUrl, $Creds, $PackagePath) {

    $stopLoop = $false
    $retryCount = 0

    do {
        try {

            Connect-PnPOnline $SiteFullUrl -Credentials $Creds

            Add-PnPApp -Path $PackagePath -Scope Site -Publish -Overwrite -SkipFeatureDeployment -ErrorAction Stop

            Write-Host $("ProvisioningCommon:AddApp: Job completed for " + $PackagePath)

            $stopLoop = $true
        }
        catch [Exception] {
            if ($retryCount -gt 30){
                Write-Host $("ProvisioningCommon:AddApp: Max retry for " + $PackagePath)
                $stopLoop = $true
            }
            else {
                Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -ForegroundColor Yello
                Write-Host $("ProvisioningCommon:AddApp: Could not complete retrying in 10 seconds... " + $PackagePath)
                Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
                $retryCount = $retryCount + 1
            }
        }
    } while ($stopLoop -eq $false)
}
```

Reference URL:

https://blog.velingeorgiev.com/sitecollectionappcatalog-cannot-find-resource-for-the-request

Comment: Thank you, I will give this a try :)